# How to get last value from filter formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using a Filter Formula Which gives several output. But I need the last one.

Here is my formula:-

`=Filter(weather!E:E,weather!U:U="d",DATEVALUE(weather!V:V)=Today())`

This gives me out put `a,b,c`
but I want the last value only `c`. What is the work around?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, provide a sample sheet that we can edit, and show the output you want on that sheet, if you expect people to be able to help you.  What is your input data that you are filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `COUNT` (or `COUNTA`) to count how many results returns your formula, then use `INDEX` to get the last result.

Example

Let say, that we have

[image]

The following formula will return `C`

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A1:A4,B1:B4=2),COUNTA(FILTER(A1:A4,B1:B4=2)))
```